# Calculating F-Score using LOOCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, accuracy

I am a machine learning novice and currently evaluating my decision tree model using the LOOCV.
From my research I know that the accuracy can be calculated using LOOVC however I was wondering if it is ok to calculate the f_score as well.
The code I wrote for this is below:

```
    for train_index, test_index in loo.split(loo_X):
        X_train, X_test = loo_X.iloc[train_index], loo_X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = loo_y.iloc[train_index], loo_y.iloc[test_index]
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
        f_score.append(f1_score(y_test, y_predict, zero_division=1))
        score.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict) * 100)
    print(np.array(f_score).mean())
    print(np.array(score).mean())
```

Update

```
    y_test_all = []
    y_predict = []
    for train_index, test_index in loo.split(loo_X):
        X_train, X_test = loo_X.iloc[train_index], loo_X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = loo_y.iloc[train_index], loo_y.iloc[test_index]
        y_test_all.append(y_test)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_predict.append(clf.predict(X_test))
    print(f1_score(y_test_all, y_predict, zero_division=1))
```

Comment: There is no "mean score" using LOOCV, you save the output class for each fold and at the end you evaluate the model on all the predictions.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you, my wording was incorrect. Is my code ok in terms of finding the f_score?

Comment: As I see it, no. You save the result of y_predict in an array, and after the loop - when you have all the predictions, you evaluate your f-score on y_test and y_predict.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you, so from what I interepreted from your comment I have added the ytest and ypredict outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you save each prediction from each fold, and you evaluate your metric only at the end, once you have all the predictions, with the true y label. Some sort of pseudocode:

```
data_y
data_x
preds = []
for i in 1:len(data_y):
    model <- model trained on all except the i-th row
    preds <- append prediction from the model above for the i-th row
f_score(data_y,preds)
```